# can we run rotary compressor of Air conditioner with different frequency level?

Tags: compressors, compressed-air

I am working on split type AC compressor. I actually want to know, if i changed the frequency of the compressor to run on different power level, will it affect the life of the compressor. My actual work to run the Compressor with different power level. I will use VFD ( variable frequency drive) to change the frequency of compressor and it will take different power with respect to the frequency. can you tell me that all rotary compressor is designed for a specific frequency. ?

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited on Electrical Engineering ...

Comment: I have posted there this same question, they refer me on this forum

Comment: I actually want to know, is there a problem if we change the frequency of compressor . are the compressor are designed on specific frequency

Comment: The compressor is designed to run a a certain speed ie rpm, is it a piston type compressor or axial? If you are using a vfd to change the speed of the drive motor, if that is possible with that motor, then the compressor speed will change and so will the life within limits as too slow may reduce lubrication and therefore reduce life...

Comment: Is there documentation with the unit?  Have you tried looking there?  What is the design of the unit?  On a side note, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary-screw_compressor#Variable_speed) seems to only say good things about a VFD as a control scheme (besides the cost).  It's not exactly a comprehensive review, but it's something.

Comment: Do we really need this question twice?  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/can-we-run-rotary-compressor-of-air-conditioner-with-different-frequency-level

Comment: @solarMike That one was migrated.   I assume OP is new to SE and didn't realize it would be migrated and made the duplicate to move it here.  Anyways,  I've voted to close the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, we don't know what compressor you have so we can't answer definitively. MANY compressors are indeed designed to operate at a very narrowly specific speed because the lubrication of it is dependent on that speed. Also, are you working with a compressor that would use a 3 phase motor? Because for the most part VFDs only work on 3 phase motors. There are a few that work on SOME types of single phase motors, but the type of motors that will work are not the types that are typically used on compressors.