# can we run rotary compressor of Air conditioner with different frequency level ?

Tags: cooling

I am working on split type AC compressor. I actually want to know, if i changed the frequency of the compressor to run on different power level, will it affect the life of the compressor. My actual work to run the Compressor with different power level. I will use VDF ( variable frequency drive) to change the frequency of compressor and it will take different power with respect to the frequency. 
can you tell me that all rotary compressor is designed for a specific frequency. ?

Comment: I suppose instead of closing it, you could ask a moderator to move it.

Comment: Many compressors are in fact designed for a narrowly specific frequency, especially if they rely upon mechanical lubrication. Only your specific compressor mfr can answer this question.